ant.design datepicker custom input component
I tried to add my input to the datapicker with a mask. But I ran into a problem. It is not possible to enter values ​​with this approach, or to call the calendar itself when focused
import { DatePicker as AntdDatePicker } from "antd";
import MaskedInput from "react-text-mask";
import React, { useState } from "react";

export function DatePicker(props) {
  const InputComponent = (propsInput) => {
    return (
      <MaskedInput
        {...propsInput}
        mask={[
          /[0-3]/,
          /[0-9]/,
          ".",
          /[0-1]/,
          /[0-9]/,
          ".",
          /[1-2]/,
          /\d/,
          /\d/,
          /\d/,
        ]}
        placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy"
      />
    );
  };
  return (
    <AntdDatePicker
      disabled={props?.isDisabled}
      disabledDate={props?.isDisabledDate}
      open={props?.isOpen}
      readOnly={props?.isReadonly}
      components={{
        input: InputComponent,
      }}
    />
  );
}

help
I tried to put in the ref but without success

The customized input component should support ref.
import { DatePicker as AntdDatePicker } from "antd";
import MaskedInput from "react-text-mask";
import React, { useState } from "react";

export function DatePicker(props) {
  const InputComponent = React.forwardRef((propsInput, ref) => {
    return (
      <MaskedInput
        {...propsInput}
        mask={[
          /[0-3]/,
          /[0-9]/,
          ".",
          /[0-1]/,
          /[0-9]/,
          ".",
          /[1-2]/,
          /\d/,
          /\d/,
          /\d/,
        ]}
        placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy"
        render={(textMaskRef, props) => (
          <input
            {...props}
            ref={(node) => {
              if (node) {
                textMaskRef(node);
                if (ref) {
                  ref.current = node;
                }
              }
            }}
          />
        )}
      />
    );
  });
  return (
    <AntdDatePicker
      open={props?.isOpen}
      readOnly={props?.isReadonly}
      components={{
        input: InputComponent,
      }}
    />
  );
}

Output:

codesandbox

what if the input is from antd?
